# ORDER BY in HANA not the same rule as in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, hana

I have a sorting problem with the result of a query in SAP HANA, here's the result:

```
15-1367
15-1367-BOX
15-1367BO
15-1367BO-AU
15-1367BO-BOX
```

But the sort in Excel shows this:

```
15-1367
15-1367BO
15-1367BO-AU
15-1367BO-BOX
15-1367-BOX
```

So as you can for the ID 15-1367-BOX, in Excel the dash comes after the letters while the sort in the query returns the dash before the letters. 
How can I sort in HANA with the same sorting rule as in Excel???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with excel as this is correctly sorted by HANA. (whether EBCIDIC or ASCII '-' comes before 'B'.

The key thing to note below is the last paragraph in the quote!

Excel has this idiosyncrasy:

> When you sort a column that contains alphanumeric characters, the sort
>   may return unexpected results. Excel sorts the values left to right,
>   character by character. For example, if a cell contains the text
>   "A100," Excel places the cell after a cell that contains the entry
>   "A1" and before a cell that contains the entry "A11."
>
> Excel sorts data in the following order:
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (space) ! " # $ % & ( ) * , . / : ; ? @ [ \ ] ^ _
>   ` { | } ~ + < = > A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> Apostrophes (') and hyphens (-) are ignored, with one exception: If
>   two text strings are the same except for a hyphen, the text with the
>   hyphen is sorted last.

Source: [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/322067/how-to-correctly-sort-alphanumeric-data-in-excel)

To solve this problem you could create a helper column and substitute the hyphen with, say (as an example - you would have to vet your data) an '&' - or select an appropriate character from the above that would achieve the same correct outcome HANA does. Then include the helper column in the sort.

**Implementation:**
Create a column next to your Excel Column and use this formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(G5,"-","&")`
(It's very important you choose a character 1) that your data does not have and 2) that is reflected in the quote above)

I then select both columns, sorting on the HELPER column!
The data is now in the same order as the HANA order.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to create this helper column, could you show me how to do it? Or wouldn't it be easier to use a regex in the query to avoid the Excel manipulation?

Comment: refer to the new implementation section